# Get TH of a TD in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I get the TH of a TD in Datatables? Right now I have a code which I can use to add an attribute to the TD's on a datatable:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
   $('td', nRow).attr("title","PUMMM");
   //takes the tds from the row and assigned title attribute
 }
```

What I want to do is to put a different attribute depending on the header that the particular td have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Sorry, i dont know this plugin...

```
var columNumber = 0; 
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    $('td, th', nRow).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this[0].tagName == "TD"){
                switch(columnNumber)
                {
                    case 0:
                        $this.attr("title","Column 0");
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        $this.attr("title","Column 1");
                        break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .   

                }
                columnNumber++;
        }

    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve my problem using your code with some modifications, I made a edit, I assigned a number to each column, so now I can know on which column I'm working on. Please approve the edit to vote the answer.